# FormIO - Reorder the pages in formIO by dragging and rearranging

Tags: angular, formio, angular-formio

I want to swap page 3 and page 4. Is it possible to reorder the FormIO pages by dragging and reordering them?
[FormIO Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFXDi.png)

I checked the possibilities of adding CDK-drag-drop to the existing FormIO Pages. But it didn't work.

Comment: @brendanbond  Kindly help with this

Comment: Hi! This is not quite possible via drag & drop, but you should very trivially be able to reorder the page components by manipulating the form's JSON definition.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.